# "Sharing without a URL" not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

According to the [Google+ iOS SDK docs](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#sharing_without_a_url), you can Share to Google+ by doing this:

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {
  id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

  // This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
  // item you're sharing.
  [shareBuilder setTitle:@"New 5k record!"
             description:@"I just ran 5000 meters in 26:16! That's a new record!";
            thumbnailURL:@"https://www.example.com/images/5krun.png"];

  [shareBuilder open];
}
```

However, the `description` "I just ran 5000 meters in 26:16! That's a new record!" does NOT show up on your profile page after sharing, only the `title` and `thumbnailURL` do.  The description is present in the preview of what will be shared but when you share it it is not there.

Also, the docs don't say this but you have to call

`[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"some id here"];`

otherwise the SDK prints this out:

```
-[GPPShareBuilderImpl getURL] Content deep-link ID is required with title and description.
```

The fact that the docs don't mention that makes me think it is out of date and I need to do something else to get the description to be shared.  Has anyone gotten the description to show up?

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you find the solution? @OpenUserX03

Comment: No, I never found a solution for this.

Comment: My problem is the image doesn't shown. (I changed the different image size. All doesn't work.) Any idea?

Comment: @bagusflyer did you find any solution for this?